# I want to amend several columns in a consecutive way based on serial ID without rbind as columns headings are not identical

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

Instead of copy and paste corresponding columns into excel, I want to amend several columns in a **consecutive way** based on serial ID named `addr`.

Assume my data sets are like these

```
df1 <- data.frame(addr=c('a','b','c','d'), 
                  num = c(1,2,3,4),
                  x=c(1, NA,4,5));df1

df2 <- data.frame(addr=c('e','f','g'), 
                  num=c(100,200,500));df2

var<-intersect(names(df), names(df2));var
combined.df<-merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = var, all=T);combined.df

df3 <- data.frame(addr=c('e','f','g'), 
                  x=c(5,7,NA));df3

var<-intersect(names(df3), names(combined.df));var
combined.df<-merge(x = combined.df, y = df3, by = var, all=T);combined.df
```

The current output is

```
  addr  x num
1    a  1   1
2    b NA   2
3    c  4   3
4    d  5   4
5    e  5  NA
6    e NA 100
7    f  7  NA
8    f NA 200
9    g NA 500
```

The desired output is

```
  addr  x num
1    a  1   1
2    b NA   2
3    c  4   3
4    d  5   4
5    e  5  100
6    f  7  200
7    g NA  500
```

**i.e.: Overwrite empty columns without deleting prior full cells**

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to automate using a `for` loop, place the datasets in a `list` except the first one, then create a copy of the first dataset as 'out', loop over the sequence of the `list`, `merge` the first one i.e 'out' with the corresponding `list` elements, specify the `by` as `intersect` of `names` of both datasets and update by assigning (`<-`) back to the 'out'

```
out <- df1
lst1 <- list(df2, df3)
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {
  out <- merge(out, lst1[[i]],
       by = intersect(names(out), names(lst1[[i]])), all = TRUE)
 }
```

Then, we change the output by grouping over the 'addr', and `summarise` `across` all other columns by removing the `NA` if there exist a non-NA element

```
library(dplyr)
out %>% 
    group_by(addr) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(),
            ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA_real_ else .[!is.na(.)]), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
#  addr      x   num
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1     1
#2 b        NA     2
#3 c         4     3
#4 d         5     4
#5 e         5   100
#6 f         7   200
#7 g        NA   500
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Upvoted and checked as a solution. I will try it on my large dataset and will let you know if I got any comments then. Appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to `ignore.case` i.e. `Age` is ` dataset to be merged with `age` in the big dataset. Appreciate your input.

Comment: ```Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must return compatible vectors across groups
i Result type for group NA (Serial.ID.COMBINED = NA): <character>.
i Result type for group NA (Serial.ID.COMBINED = NA): <double>.
i Input `..1` is `across(everything(), ~if (all(is.na(.))) NA_real_ else .[!is.na(.)])`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred Warning :
1: In cnd_bullet_combine_details(e$parent$x, e$parent$x_arg) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In cnd_bullet_combine_details(e$parent$y, e$parent$y_arg) :
  NAs introduced by coercion```

Comment: I got the prior error after applying your code to my large dataset, Any advise?

Comment: @MohamedRahouma Is it because your larger dataset have unequal number of non-NA elements per each column by group

Comment: Yes, I think so. I managed it by putting all my needed variables in a separate dataset then used regular merging instead of the consecutive manner that I asked for, Appreciate.